# meteor and java app data push

Tags: java, mongodb, meteor, ddp

I have this set up - Java application is collecting and pushing data to mongodb for client side to retrieve and display. I want to try to use meteor for the client side. What is the best approach with meteor:

- use DDPClient to connect to meteor's mongodb and *only* push data to it 
  or
- configure meteor to point to my existing mongodb that is already collecting data from my Java application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both should work - the short answer. The longer answer:

- Using DDPClient for Java is important if your app needs to have a subset of data in sync in java client as well, it might be a big memory and computational overhead if used mindlessly
- Pointing Meteor at existing MongoDB will work if the oplog tailing is enabled and supported, otherwise there will be 10s lags between Meteor noticing new updates

Comment: Thanks, @imslavko, for the response. 10s lag is not acceptable for my client because it's streaming real time data. I actually thought that meteor took care of this 10s lag by now. Would you please elaborate on your comment about DDPClient memory and computational overhead?

Comment: Thanks, @imslavko, again for the clarification, misread the answer initially.